# How do I use wildcards with LINQ?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

How do I modify the follwing LINQ query so that orgainizationName includes wildcards? If organizationName is 'ABC', I need 'ABC (Miami, FL)' returned. The pattern is always orgName followed by a space and then, in parentheses "()", the city and state.

```
var orgId = dc.Contacts.Where(on =>
on.ContactTypeID == 2 &&
on.IsActive == true &&
on.OrganizationName.Contains(organizationName)
)
.Select(on => on.ContactID).SingleOrDefault();
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to normalize your data a bit.

Comment: It is what we have to work with. The organization name is in it's own set of fields. I don't agree with this but it's not getting changed anytime soon.

Comment: What about organizations that are in two cities? Xanatos answer is no better...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
on.OrganizationName.StartsWith(organizationName + " (");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var orgId = dc.Contacts.Where(on =>
    on.ContactTypeID == 2 &&
    on.IsActive == true &&
    on.OrganizationName.StartsWith(organizationName))
        .Select(on => on.ContactID).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: See @Albin's comment. Your really should have the Org's location in its own field separate from the name.

Comment: I considered using .StartwsWith() but that could still return a list of matches - the reason for the question. The concatenation above should work fine.

Comment: Then for your data, it must not be possible to have an organization name for more than one location, right? Otherwise @xanatos answer is no different than mine regarding a list of matches. ABC (New York, NY) and ABC (Chicago, IL) both are valid in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `on.OrganizationName.StartsWith(organizationName)`